# Resharper 10: Unit test output window is broken

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper, resharper-10.0

So I've upgraded Resharper to version 10 (on VS2015), and now Unit Tests don't show output anymore in all our solutions:

[image: Unit test output]

This is very annoying because I want to see the reason why a test fails. The workaround for now is to use the new "Stack trace explorer", where the result is visible.

Oddly enough, when I create a brand new solution and write a simple test, the output window still works as it did!

Any ideas? Could this be a configuration issue?

Comment: Thanks for posting about this frustrating problem. I thought, I was alone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an unfortunate show stopper bug ([RSRP-450266](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450266)) that slipped through at the last minute. It's been fixed for a 10.0.1 hot fix release that should be out very soon (most likely sometime during next week).

As a short term workaround, don't click on parent nodes in the tree, only click on tests. If you click on a parent node, the output pane gets stuck and stops updating. If it does get stuck, right click on the tests you want to run and select "Create new session", a new tab will open, and you'll be able to run the tests again. Apologies, it's not a great workaround, but at least it'll keep you going for a few days until the hot fix is available.